# Page refresh with GET request after a .submit() and fetch(method: 'POST')

Tags: javascript, php, post, get, fetch

I've been trying to create a form with multiple submit buttons, but failing miserably. I have researched and read many, many articles and feel I am getting close, but I have come across a blocker. I have simplified my code as much as I can, but obviously it is part of a much larger code base. I have an HTML page that creates a new Class from a Javascript file. That class uses a php file to

1. Create a form
2. process the results of the form.

The Javascript also adds various events.

The problem I am having is that after the fetch to process the results that uses the POST method, another GET method (params as part of the URL) refreshes the page.
I have tried various fixes, some of which are:

1. Adding `event.preventDefault();` (and moving it's position)
2. Adding `return false;` (and moving it's position).
3. Moving the buttons out of the form. (someone said that was causing a second submit).
4. Adding a blank action to the form and other values (currently a #)

My HTML code is.

```
    <div class="scratch_container"> </div>
    <script src="scratch.js"></script>
    <script>
    new Scratch();
    </script>
```

My Javascript is.

```
class Scratch {

    constructor(options) {
        let defaults = {
          container: document.querySelector(".scratch_container"),
          php_file_url: "scratch.php"
        };
        this.options = Object.assign(defaults, options);
        this.initialise();
    }

    initialise() {
        let url = `${this.options.php_file_url}?process_type=A`;
        fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
          this.options.container.innerHTML = data;
          this._eventHandlers();
        });
    }

    _eventHandlers() {
      this.options.container.querySelectorAll(".scratch_main .action").forEach(action => {
        action.onclick = event => {
          this.options.container.querySelector(".scratch_main form").submit();
          fetch(`${this.options.php_file_url}?process_type=C`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new FormData(this.options.container.querySelector(".scratch_main form"))
          }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
              this.options.container.querySelector(".scratch_main .message").innerHTML = data.text;
          }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error)
          });;
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        };
      });
    }

}
```

An finally the php.

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['process_type']) {
case "C":
      $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'text' =>
        'Form Data<br />' .
        'input_1  ' . $_POST['input_1'] . '<br />' .
        'input_2  ' . $_POST['input_2'] . '<br />' .
        'action  ' . $_POST['action']));
      die($output);
      break;
case "A":
?>
  <div class="scratch_main">
    <div class="message"> </div>
    <form action="#">
        <input name="input_1" value="input 1" type="text">
        <input name="input_2" value="input 2" type="text">
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <button class="action" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="action" name="action" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <?php
  break;
default:
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' =>  'No switch code!'));
  die($output);
}
?>
```

I know there are many threads, even on stackoverflow that discuss this problem and I think I have read everyone and tried implementing fixes that worked for them, but I still get the the same results.

I am running this on a hosted server with ionos using php 7.4. The first html is being run as PHP.

Comment: Hi! is your objective reloading the page after a submit or not to?  Can you provide a clearer and concise question? Thx :)

Comment: Can you once again summarize your problem in a single sentence?

Comment: My problem is, the button clicks happen and the fetch/POST method happen OK, but then it looks like the default form action happens - a GET method and the page reloads. It shouldn't reload.